# Correct script construct to monitor RaspPi sound card output and execute CEC command to activate AV receiver?

Tags: bash

Apologies in advance - I'm a complete beginner so the code below is probably a car crash but I'd really appreciate any help if anyone can spare a minute?

Aim - I have my RaspPi as a music source to my AV receiver. I've installed libcec onto RPi and the receiver is cec enabled so I am trying to write a script that sends the 'active source' command to the AVR whenever the sound card is active.

The active source command:

```
echo 'as' | cec-client -d 1 -s
```

The script to return sound card status:

```
grep RUNNING /proc/asound/card*/pcm*/sub*/status
```

I've tried to represent the following logic:
1. If music is playing - send active command (turns on AVR with correct channel) and create the empty file 'yamaha-yes'
2. If yamaha-yes file exists check that music is playing - if not then remove 'yamaha-yes' file.
The idea with the yamaha-yes file is to prevent the script from continually sending the active source command whilst music is playing - it just needs sending once, so I've tried to write it so that the presence of the file whilst music playing leads to no further action.

I was hoping to use the 'watch' command from boot to have this running continually.

```
#!/bin/bash

musicon="$( grep RUNNING /proc/asound/card*/pcm*/sub*/status )"
file="/etc/yamaha-yes"

if [ -e $file ] ; then
    if [ "$musicon" = "" ] ; then
    sudo rm /etc/yamaha-yes
    fi
else
    if [ "$musicon" ] ; then
        echo 'as' | cec-client -d 1 -s
        sudo touch /etc/yamaha-yes
    fi
fi
```

The current error returned is 'line 8: [: too many arguments'. But I suspect there is a lot more wrong with it than that and was hoping to check I was on the right track before flogging it any further!

Thanks in advance! Tom

EDIT

Some changes made in line with Marc's advice and the code now seems to work - though I realise it still isn't the most elegant read! Perhaps there is a better way of scripting it?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you are missing quotes `[ "$musicon" = 'RUNNING' ]`. However, there are problems with how your grepping is going to work. When audio is running you could end up with multiple RUNNING values (giving the string `RUNNING\nRUNNING` or longer) returned which will not equal `RUNNING`. Also, `$musicoff` is broken because the `!` command doesnt change a commands output, only its return value. `"$musicoff"` will equal `RUNNING` only if audio is running, which is the exact opposite of what you want. Fortunately, the fix also simplifies the script.

The behavior of `grep` is that it returns 0 (true) if it found the search text anywhere, otherwise it returns 1 (false). So, instead of comparing the output of grep against a specific value (which might fail in certain cases) use the return value of grep directly:

```
musicon="grep RUNNING /proc/asound/card*/pcm*/sub*/status"
if $musicon ; then
    echo Music is on;
fi

if ! $musicon; then
    echo Music is off;
fi
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this Marc - prior to seeing this i'd made some changes which I've edited into the original post - sorry thought it was easiest rather than trying to  post all over again. I was hoping the creation of 'yamaha-yes' file would prevent the script from constantly getting 'RUNNING' back as it wouldn't command grep whilst the file exists. I went for `"$musicon" = ""` rather than  `! "$musicon"` - is the outcome the same?

Comment: I cant think of any corner cases that will cause problems between `! $musicon` and `[ "$musicon" = "" ]`, although I believe the first syntax to be cleaner.

Comment: The basic explanation is fine, but putting the command in a variable and running it twice is horrible.  Just do `if grep -q ...; then echo yes; else echo no; fi` or even short-circuit to `grep -q ... && echo yes || echo no`.

Comment: triplee - for my script don't i have to run the `musicon` command in both 'branches' of the if/else script? It shouldn't lead to running the command twice as it only features once in each of the branches...